# how to access the value of a variable in php

Tags: php

So I have the following:

```
    $audio1_1 = "x";
    $audio2_1 = "z";
    $audio3_1 = "r";
    $audio4_1 = "b";
    $audio5_1 = "x";
    $audio6_1 = "z";
    $audio7_1 = "r";
    $audio8_1 = "b";

    for ($x = 1; $x <= 8; $x++) {
      //// what to put here to access the corresponding value???
    }
```

I mean when $x=1 I want to get the value of $audio1_1, when $x=2 I want to get the value of $audio2_1 and so on.
Thank you!

Comment: `echo ${'audio' . $x . '_1'};`

Comment: you could also add them to an array, and then access it like `array[pos]`

Comment: Thank you so much Philipp and everyone else that answered. I appreciate your help immensely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shoud use arrays, if you want to store many values

```
$audio[] = "x";
$audio[] = "z";
$audio[] = "r";
$audio[] = "b";
$audio[] = "x";
$audio[] = "z";
$audio[] = "r";
$audio[] = "b";

foreach ($audio as $value) {
  //// do something with $value
}
```

if you cant do this and you have to use your $audioX_1 var names, you could do something like this

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 8; $x++) {
    $varname = "audio{$x}_1";
    $value = $$varname;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use arrays.

```
$audio = array("x", "z", "r", "b", "x", "z", "r", "b");
foreach ($audio as $audioTemp) 
{
  $audioTemp //will be x then z then r and so on
}
```

Comment: arrays are zero based - you have to edit your for loop

Comment: @Philipp noticed, fixed

Comment: you should also use `count` instead of fixed values

Answer (score 0):

```
    $audio1_1 = "x";
    $audio2_1 = "z";
    $audio3_1 = "r";
    $audio4_1 = "b";
    $audio5_1 = "x";
    $audio6_1 = "z";
    $audio7_1 = "r";
    $audio8_1 = "b";

    for ($x = 1; $x <= 8; $x++) {
        $varName="audio".$x."_1";
        echo $$varName;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$audio1_1 = "x";
$audio2_1 = "z";
$audio3_1 = "r";
$audio4_1 = "b";
$audio5_1 = "x";
$audio6_1 = "z";
$audio7_1 = "r";
$audio8_1 = "b";

for ($x = 1; $x <= 8; $x++) {
    $var = "audio".$x."_1";
    print $$var; 
}
```